# Android:Push notification in mobile when any new post posted in website

Tags: php, android, notifications, web

I need to get notification on android device when changes or any new post are posted in the website. I did some search but still I am not clear with this. I finished my notification part but I am not clear with how to get the new post which is posted in website as notification. Someone please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PUSH notification from the forum. You need to register in google apps and authorize your forum app to make push notifications. Than, change your forum to send PUSH on new post event.

Check this link for more info: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: i want it as an android app. Without registering in google apps can we do this?

Comment: You can check your forum via API every minute, for example. If last_post_id in app and in forum result are different - you have new posts.

Comment: thanks for your idea.. I am going to check the above notification for my "Wordpress" website... I should get this notification through an android app, so i should use android API or Wordpress API.